# Avoiding 'Buffer Overrun' C6386 warning

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, warnings, buffer-overrun

In my code, I am using an array `xyz` of 10 objects. When I am trying to access an element of the array using an unsigned int index like this: `xyz[level]`, I get ['Buffer overrun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182089.aspx)' warning. Logically, I am pretty sure that level won't exceed 10. How to avoid this warning?

Comment: Can you post the code where you're getting the warning?

Comment: Not sure. This is a pretty big code base I am working on. I am trying to reproduce it with a small example. Let me post it when I succeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm probably teaching my grandmother to suck eggs here, but do remember that "level won't exceed 10" is wrong for an array of size 10:

```
char a[10];
a[10] = '\0';  // Bug, and "Buffer Overrun" warning.
```

Comment: +1, because I'm pretty sure that's exactly the reason why the OP gets the warning.

Comment: Yes, this is somewhat related to my issue. I did a check like this `if (level < 10)` before accessing like this `xyz[level]` and the warning vanished.

Comment: Answered my question

Answer (score 3):

Are you *really* sure? I never got this warning until now. So, double check.

Anyway, you can use the

```
#pragma warning( disable: 6386 )
```

preprocessor directive. I usually push and pop this to the "pragma stack"

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 6386 )
// Some code
#pragma warning( pop )
```

as advised [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: That is fairly dangerous as the warning might be caused by a bug.  Only ever silence warnings if you are **CERTAIN** what caused them and that it is harmless.